# Reactive Extension : 3 Consecutive occurance of a Record

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have a hot observable -

Class TableRecord

```
{
    string propertyA;
    DateTime dt;
    Dictionary<string,int> checkThreshHoldValues;
}
```

I need to check for each value present in the dictionary, if the 3 consecutive values are exceeding the threshold or not. If yes, I need to generate a new event for that property. (Here each reacord will come at a different of 15 minutes ie 4 records in 1 hour.

```
Class GeneratedRecord
{
  string propertyA;
  DateTime lastTimeObserved;
  string dictionaryPropertyName;
  int lastValue
}
```

I know I have to use groupByUntil with Buffer, but somehow I am unable to think , how to split the dictionary into individual parts with still keeping the condition
Any help will be appreciated.

Example : Lets say I have PropertyA value is in {"TownA","TownB","TownC"}
Lets say my properties in dictionary are {"Pollution","Temperature","Pressure"}

Lets say, I am recv values per 15 minutes, so my data is say -

```
{"TownA" ,"6/14/2015 10:00",{ {"Pollution",61},{"Temperature",48},{"Pressure",40}}}

{"TownA" ,"6/14/2015 10:15",{ {"Pollution",63},{"Temperature",63},{"Pressure",40}}}

{"TownA" ,"6/14/2015 10:30",{ {"Pollution",49},{"Temperature",64},{"Pressure",40}}}
{"TownA" ,"6/14/2015 10:45",{ {"Pollution",70},{"Temperature",65},{"Pressure",40}}}
```

Say for Threshhold value is 60.
So with above example, only Temperature satisfies the condition as it has value of {63,64,65 } . For pollution only 2 consecutive values were above 60

regards

Comment: Can you please provide the code that creates your hot observable, and also compilable code for your two classes? Then can you please explain what you mean by "3 consecutive values are exceeding the threshold"? What record are you talking about that will come 4 times an hour?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with overlapping windows but I couldn't work out the syntax to start a new window every time an element is received and close the window when it contains three items. But here is a conceptual solution based on Observable.Create and maintaining a queue. In this case I use Interval and a simple threshold (>3):

```
Observable.Create<string>(observer =>
{
    var queue = new Queue<long>(3);



    return Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Subscribe(value =>
    {
        if (queue.Count == 3)
        {
            queue.Dequeue();
        }

        queue.Enqueue(value);

        if (queue.Count == 3)
        {
            var values = queue.ToArray();
            if (values.All(v => v > 3))
            {
                observer.OnNext("All above 3. " + values[0] + " " + values[1] + " " + values[2]);
            }
        }
    });
})
```